# implement a base class method to access a property of derived classes

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I have a base class and several derived classes which can have more than one instances.
The derived classes have a static string, in which the nationality name is stored.
Looks like this...

```
// Base Class
class Person{
    private:
        // Informations that every person has. Not depending on the nationality
        unsigned char m_size;
        char[] m_name;

    public:
        // Get the human readable name of a nationality
        void getNationalityName(char* pNatiName);
}

void Base::getNationalityName(char* pNatiName);
{
    strcpy(pNatiName, m_nationalityName);
}


// A derived class
class American : public Person{
    private:
        unsigned int m_dollar;
        static char[] m_nationalityName;
}

// Another derived class
class Russian : public Person{
    private:
        unsigned int m_rubel;
        static char[] m_nationalityName;
}
```

I would now like to access the nationality name with the method "getNationalityName" from one of the derived classes.
The problem is, that the base class doesn't know that a derived class has a property called "m_nationalityName".

I could implement the "getNationalityName" method in each class but i think that's not the right way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use polymorphism. Make your `getNationalityName` function `virtual`, and redefine it in your derived classes to return the desired string. Each time, the derived class' function will be called, returning the string of the corresponding class:

```
//base class:
class Person{
    <...>

    public:
        virtual void getNationalityName(char* pNatiName);
}

<...>

// A derived class
class American : public Person{
    public:
        void getNationalityName(char* pNatiName)
        {
            strcpy(pNatiName, m_nationalityName);
        }
    private:
        unsigned int m_dollar;
        static char[] m_nationalityName;
}

<...>

int main()
{
    Person * p = new American();
    p->getNationalityName(<...>); // calls American::getNationalityName name even though p is a pointer to the base class.
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a nice solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't. The design looks flawed. The nationality should be a property (i.e. data member) of a person. What if someone has 2 nationalities?

```
enum Nationality
{
   ROMANIAN,
   AMERICAN,
   RUSSIAN,
};

class Person
{
   Nationality nationality; // or std::vector<Nationality> nationalities;
};
```

The enum value can be easily converterd afterwards.

Comment: I think the OP wants a string representation to print it out, or something like that...

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall the subsequent conversion is trivial. My main point was not to have that class hierarchy.

Comment: yeah that's true. Also this is just an example in my case no person could have two nationalities, sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `m_nationalityName` should be put in your base class `person`. To me, nationality is more like an attribute of `person`. Just don't make it `static` because you don't want to have all your persons share the same nationality.

Comment: yeah i was also thinking of that... but then all persons would have the same nationality name wouldn't they? Or will there be a new static property instance for each derived class?

Comment: I think each nationality should be a class because every nationality will have other different properties and methods

Comment: OK. If that's true, one thing you can do is create a new class for nationality, and use the composition pattern, i.e. let nationality be the member of your Person class.

Answer (score 0):

I think this scenario can hanle like this. because different Nationality just has different name, not different behavior, so do not need use polymorphism

```
  class Nationality
  {
  private:
        Nationality(const char* name_i):m_name(name_i)
        {
        }
        const char * m_name;
  public:
        static Nationality& American()
        {
             static Nationality country("American");
             return country;
        }

        static Nationality& Russian()
        {
             static Nationality country("Russia");
        }

        void getName(char* pNatiName) const
        {
            strcpy(pNatiName, m_name);
        }

   };


   class Person
   {
   private:
        <................>
        Nationality* nationality

   public:
       void getNationalityName(char* pNatiName)const
       {
             nationality->getName(pNatiName);
       }

   };
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), you can do this:

```
template<class T>
class Person {
    static const std::string m_nationalityName;

    // ...
};

template<class T> const std::string Person<T>::m_nationalityName = "Unknown";

class American : public Person<American> {
    // ...
};

template<> const std::string Person<American>::m_nationalityName = "American";

class Russian : public Person<Russian> {
    // ...
};

template<> const std::string Person<Russian>::m_nationalityName = "Russian";
```

Does not work with `char[]`.

Comment: -1 For one thing it's not a good solution for the given problem because an American is not a Person anymore. Second, it totally works with char[]

Comment: I tried using `char[]`, it wouldn't compile because the strings had different lengths. I don't see how an American is not a person anymore.

Comment: An American is not a Person, it is a Person<American>. You do not have a polymorphic Person base-class anymore.

Comment: Well, you can of course split it into a polymorphic `Person` and a templated `PersonWithNationality`, or use a traits struct. I just wanted to demonstrate how to define static class fields that have different values for each derived class.